# El primer PDF siempre está vacío

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Este código debe descargar un PDF que muestre el contenido de una lista de noticias de una página (es un "div"), pero cada que añado un nuevo elemento a la lista o refresco la página, siempre el primer PDF resultante está en blanco y no encuentro el error.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

Script:

```
<script src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
function saveDiv(divId) {
  doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML);
  doc.save('news_fecha_hora.pdf');
}
</script>
```

Fragmento del código principal:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!--Botón para realizar la descarga del div en PDF, ejecuta el script "saveDiv(divId)"-->
      <form class="" method="post" id="DescargarNoticiasPdf">
        <input type="hidden" name="dom" value="">
        <!--ONCLICK ejecuta la función saveDiv()-->
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="saveDiv('canvas')" title="Descarga las noticias mostradas">Descargar PDF</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--Esta es la sección que me interesa guardar como PDF-->
    <!--El ID del div de interés es 'canvas'-->
    <div class="col-md-8" id="canvas">
      <div id="ListaNoticias">
        <?php
          foreach($_SESSION['noticias'] as $noticia) :
        ?>
        <div class="">
          <!--Contenido de la noticia-->
          <!--imágen-->
          <!--descripción-->
          <!--etc-->
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Primer y segundo PDF resultantes:
[image: Este es el primer PDF que descarga]

[image: Segundo PDF que se descarga, sin haber hecho ningún cambio]

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo con código HTML y cómo ejecutas la función para generar PDFs.

Comment: <script src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>

debees retirar uno de los 2, tienes repetido el script eso podria estar afectando

Comment: Gracias @Triby, ya la edité.

Comment: Retiré "jspdf.js" y funciona exactamente igual, @JhonnattanRivera. Si retiro "jspdf.min.js" deja de reconocerme la función "document" y "saveDiv()" y no hace nada más. Gracias

Comment: Las imágenes no son necesarias y, además: 1. En el código que pusiste no se ve que asignes ID al _div_ 2. Tampoco pusiste el código con el que ejecutas la función.

Comment: @Triby, sí lo asigné, en un segundo los resalto. 1.- El div tiene asignado un id="canvas". 2.- La función se ejecuta con un onclick="saveDiv('canvas')" en el botón de "Descargar PDF".

Comment: Has mirado en la consola del navegador? Hay algún error cuando intentas generar los primeros PDF?

Comment: Ahora que lo mencionas, @Alfabravo, sí. Aparece _"jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!"_ , pero continúa apareciendo con los siguientes PDF y solo es el primero el que va en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje que proporcionas en comentarios es muy claro, necesitas enviar una función para ejecutar cuando se complete el renderizado. Al no proporcionar la función, es lógico pensar que el contenido del PDF es lo generado en la ejecución anterior.

```
// Inicializar
let doc = new jsPDF();
// Crear objeto para establecer márgenes
let margins = {
    top: 80,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 40,
    width: 522
};
function saveDiv(divId) {
  doc.fromHTML(
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML,
    margins.left,
    margins.top,
    {
        'width': margins.width, // Ancho máximo de contenido
    },
    // Función a ejecutar cuando se renderice el PDF
    function (dispose) {
      // dispose: Objeto con coordenadas X, Y de última línea
      //          permite agregar más líneas después del HTML
      // Se guarda dentro de la función, no fuera
      pdf.save('news_fecha_hora.pdf');
    },
    margins
  );
}
```

Código adaptado del ejemplo [básico de jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/basic.html), solo falta que realices las pruebas necesarias para establecer la configuración adecuada de márgenes y ancho de documento.

Comment: Te lo agradezco muchísimo :D
 Disculpa si era muy obvia la solución, pero recién me estoy acoplando a JS. Gracias por la ayuda, sirvió de mucho :D

Comment: No hay problema, lo importante es que entendiste porqué no funcionaba y pudiste solucionarlo.