# jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML! al tener una imagen en la web

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, jspdf, img

quiero hacer una conversión a pdf de mi página web, pero al tener una imagen jspdf no me renderiza la web, me deja la pantalla en blanco y me saca el siguiente error:
jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!

```
este es mi código:

 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>prueba</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="mx-5 my-5">prueba okey</h1>

    <div class="contianer my-5 mx-5" id="prueba1">
        <img src="img/debian.png" alt="">
        <h1>texto en grande</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi assumenda, modi nihil adipisci quia nesciunt
        repellendus ab laboriosam illo suscipit corporis illum fugiat eum soluta eius! Eaque nisi veniam ratione.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quod at cumque sapiente illum eveniet minus
        nostrum laboriosam beatae facilis omnis nemo, impedit fugit, autem molestiae ex culpa itaque labore?

        <h4>El usuario {{usuario.nombre}} {{usuario.apellidos}} trabaja como {{usuario.trabajo}}</h4>
    </div>




    <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var elementHTML = $('#prueba1').html();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

        doc.save('sample-document.pdf');

    </script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></s`introducir el código aquí`cript>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No se como puedo solucionarlo, y también me gustaría saber si es posible hacer una visualización del dpf en la web sin que se descargue atomáticamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [El primer PDF siempre está vacío](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389894/el-primer-pdf-siempre-est%c3%a1-vac%c3%ado)

Comment: Con lo que me has pasado, me sale la imagen pero en un tamaño muy grande, no como sale en la web, como se puede resolver eso, y muchas gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Probablemente deberías asignarle un ancho o alto máximo directamente en la etiqueta.

Comment: No, ya lo he probado pero solo baja el tamaño en el pdf, pero no lo pone tal cual se ve en la web, y para ponerlo en el pdf en la web apenas se vería la imagen, pero muchas gracias por la idea.